# Populating form fields from JSON feed using forEach or for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, foreach

I have form fields like these

```
<input id="first">
<input id="second">
<textarea id="third"></textarea>
...
```

and I need to dynamically populate them with data from a JSON feed.
**Each field's id corresponds to each JSON's key**, so I'm able to populate those fields this way:

```
first.value = feed.first;
second.value = feed.second;
third.value = feed.third;
...
```

But I would like to make it simpler.

This is what I've tried:

```
["first", "second", "third"].forEach(e => {e.value = feed[e]});
```

Sadly, it doesn't work. In console I can see JSON feed's values (`feed[e]`), but form fields are blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **document.getElementById** to get specific DOM element
and then assign the value you want.

```
const feed = {
    'first': 'hello',
    'second': 'word',
    'third': '!'
};

['first', 'second', 'third'].forEach(e => {
    document.getElementById(e).value = feed[e]
});
```

The link below is a full demonstration.
https://jsfiddle.net/2x0o8d4m/1/

Answer (score 1):

Please use eval function.

["first", "second", "third"].forEach(e => {eval(e).value = feed[e]});